# Read csv file by changeable columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm developing a software that reads a csv file and create a list for each column.
After in my program I will plot this data using `DataTime` on X coordinates and `S1;S2;S3...` as Y coordinates

My csv file:

```
DateTime;S1;S2;S3
2020-07-16 15:11:34.358231;677.0552427707063;787.6245155900142;543.0755073183745
2020-07-16 15:11:34.360247;535.4790551706492;317.65859520197984;218.64223032216418
2020-07-16 15:11:34.362263;451.9436928722545;449.5560971162404;215.33038976545765
2020-07-16 15:11:34.364279;72.31352267938303;251.55939892326035;896.9233907560412
2020-07-16 15:11:34.366295;758.7365312885398;686.7909954314093;303.9852170969752
2020-07-16 15:11:34.368311;593.8244329562257;698.5981983561348;369.11408762777785
2020-07-16 15:11:34.370327;338.56552989499176;469.327619765774;331.0295457896333
2020-07-16 15:11:34.372343;729.3276090259968;690.776181594403;97.6830657885398
2020-07-16 15:11:34.374359;284.58252864976197;569.0028638781417;196.02767689983673
2020-07-16 15:11:34.376375;909.5920826056772;178.28447193362686;240.4015082916274
```

I want to read the file by columns but this file can change the number of columns because Signals are variables. For example I can have `S1;S2;S3;S4;S5...`

So I want to be able to read the columns independently how many columns I have.
`DateTime` column is standard so I can read it 1 time.

This is my actual code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from csv import reader

class Read_csv:
    
    def csv_reader(self, file_name):
    
        with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
            csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
            csv_header = next(csv_reader)
            
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter = ';')
        self.datetime_array = list(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), df["DateTime"]))
        
        for i in range((len(csv_header)-1)):
            #TODO:read signals columns
```

My updated code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

class Read_csv:
    
    def csv_reader(self, file_name):
        

        df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter = ';', parse_dates=['DateTime']).set_index('DateTime')
        
        df.plot()
        sns.lineplot(data=df)
        
        plt.savefig("Signals_Chart.png")
```

This is my result with double legend:
[image]

Comment: Why not `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter = ';', parse_dates=['DateTime']).set_index('DateTime')` and then `df.plot()`. Seems easier. No need for all the other stuff. If you want the plot to look nicer, `import seaborn as sns` and then `sns.lineplot(data=df)` instead of `df.plot()`.

Comment: I am doing this as I don't know how many columns are in the csv file

Comment: It doesn't matter how many columns there are. Format the date as datetime, set it as the index and let the plotting api handle the rest. As you can see in my previous comment, I didn't specify the y or x axis. Your questions over the last several days have been dealing with this. Your time would be better spent by first understanding how pandas and matplotlib work together to make plotting easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The best thing to do is learn how pandas and matplotlib integrated to make data manipulation and plotting easier.
- [Pandas: Visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # for test data
import string  # for test data
from datetime import datetime  # for test data
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plt styling parameters
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)
plt.rcParams["patch.force_edgecolor"] = True

# test data with 26 columns and a date column as index
np.random.seed(365)
cols = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
length = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(length, 26) * 1000, columns=cols, index=pd.bdate_range(datetime.today(), freq='d', periods=length).tolist())

# using pandas.DataFrame.plot
df.plot()
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc="center left", borderaxespad=0)
```

[image]

## using seaborn

```py
sns.lineplot(data=df, dashes=False)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc="center left", borderaxespad=0)
```

[image]

### with your sample data in a file called `test.csv`

```py
# read in the file
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter = ';', parse_dates=['DateTime']).set_index('DateTime')

# plot the file
sns.lineplot(data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: @MatteoWes add a screenshot to the the question and the exact code you're using. If you take my example, does it plot a double legend?

Comment: Yes because I'm using "plt.savefig('filename')" that save image automatically with legend, so if I add this: "sns.lineplot(data=df)" , my legend is double

Comment: @MatteoWes If I plot the figure and add `plt.savefig('test.png')` I do not get two legends. What environment / IDE are you coding in?

Comment: @MatteoWes don't add both `df.plot` and `sns.lineplot`. Choose one. Currently you're plotting two plots on the same figure, which is why you're getting double values on the legend.

Comment: On DateTime axes (X axes), I see only the hour:minute:second as you can see in the question image, how can I change the scale to see milliseconds?

Comment: @MatteoWes that's because all the data takes place in 10 seconds. As you can see in my sample plots, the axis format adjusts for the length of the timeseries data. There are other question and documentation dealing with specifying the precise format of the x-axis and that is a different question.

Comment: @MatteoWes It's 1:50 am here. I'm going to bed.